# Is a UK Transit visa required?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

I have a Canadian travel document and I am a Permanent Resident of Canada since May 2016. I am planing to visit Germany next month (I don't need a German visa because I have a Canadian travel document).

My question is: can I stay 48 hours in the UK without a transit visa? (I have a UK visa but its validity will start on Oct. 30)

Comment: Do you actually plan to stay for exactly 48 hours?

Comment: More to the point, what @Crazydre should have asked is whether you will leave before midnight of the day after your arrival.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/transit/somewhere_else/yes) website, you don't need a visa if staying no longer than until 23:59 the next day (so less than 48 hours).

At UK border control, present:

- travel document;
- Canadian permanent resident card;
- filled-out landing card (handed out on the plane) and;
- connecting ticket to Germany.

If, for some reason, the officer tells you your visa isn't valid yet, tell them you're only applying for leave to enter in transit, on the basis of your Canadian resident card.

Comment: The traveler is presumably not arriving at the stroke of midnight, in which case the duration of the allowed stay will be shorter than 48 hours.